# Copy Constructors ... A Quandary

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, unique-ptr

I have a tree class that has move constructors and move assignment operators declared and defined.

Why would the compiler feel the need to synthesize a copy constructor and then complain that `std::unique_ptr` has private members?

This seems counterproductive. Should the compiler not be aware that hidden copy and assignment with no body or simply not defined are to prevent trying to copy a `std::unique_ptr`?

And, why does declaring and defining copy constructors and assignment operators with an empty body make the compiler happy?

Will this be cause for concern as I continue writing and building code utilizing this class?

**Additions**:

1. There is no source code because there are no source code errors ... this is a question
   that does not require presence of source code.
2. The compiler complained when the copy constructors were private so I made them public; 
   will make private again and verify if compiler hick-ups.
3. I am using Visual Studio 2012 Professional IDE and its' associated compilers.

Why is the compiler generating copy constructors in the presence of move constructors?  Seems counter-intuitive especially if copy constructors are not defined in the fist place.

**Additional Question**:

Well, it seems Visual Studio 2012 does not support = delete declarations on constructors or assignment operators and hiding my declarations causes the compiler to cry all over my code.  What do I do now?  I agree (below) that declaring do-nothing copy constructors is bad idea so what other options do I have?

If truly desiring small example, here it is.  My compiler does not support = delete

```
class Tree{
    class TreeNode{
         "declaration of unique_ptr, cstrs, move cstrs, hidden copy cstrs"
    };
public:
     "declaration of unique_ptrs, cstrs, move cstrs, copy cstrs <----- compiler 
      complains if hidden"
};
```

Using boost::variant with this

Comment: Please show your C++ source code (or a small example equivalent to it)

Comment: The compiler would only complain if you actually attempt to copy or copy assign, which is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: If you want to make sure no one is using copy constructors and assignment operators  you can define them private or ( = delete in c++11 )

Comment: Also include what compiler you are using.  Creating an empty copy constructor that does nothing is almost certainly a bad idea (especially in C++11).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there isn't a copy constructor, the compiler will attempt to generate one. The default copy constructor is pretty dumb, so it's not surprising it's tripping over bits of your class.

Defining an empty one gives you a copy constructor that doesn't do anything, and this replaces the one the compiler would otherwise have generated, thus avoiding the problem.

Comment: It's not exactly *avoiding* the problem if the copy constructor doesn't create a copy. You are just trading it in for an other problem.

Comment: You do not want an empty copy constructor that can be called: this can result in rather surprising behavior.  Hide or delete it...

Comment: @Yakk: Or just let the compiler implicitly delete it. That will happen if there's a move constructor or a non-copyable member, both of which seem to be the case here.

Comment: @MikeSeymour yes, which is why creating an empty copy constructor is often the wrong thing to do.  If the compiler is complaining about the lack of copy constructor, it is probably because you did something that tried to call it.  And if you now make an empty one and it "solves the problem", now your code tried to copy it, it finds the empty copy constructor, it does the wrong thing (maybe even eliding the empty copy constructor, so not even nothing), and then silently continues.  You solved nothing.

Comment: @Yakk: Indeed; I was just saying that there's no need to explicitly hide or delete it, as you seemed to be suggesting; just leave it deleted.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments ... very insightful

Comment: @Yakk The problem is hiding it.  VS 2012 does not support = 0 or = delete and hiding it is causing problems because boost::variant wants a copy; demands a copy forcing a do-nothing set of copy constructors otherwise the code refuses to compile and screams about the last line in my code using a unique_ptr and private declarations inside it ... bleh.

Comment: @Mushy If something wants a copy, and you give it the copy constructor it wants in blank form, when your type is move-only, you just broke your code.  Maybe `boost::variant` cannot hold `unique_ptr` containing classes.

Comment: @Yakk I need to discover the secret in a new question because this is game breaking.

Comment: @Mushy is `boost::variant` written to be move-aware?  If it is not, using it with move-only types seems like a bad idea.  What you need to do is write up a short, self contained, correct, compiling (almost) example that demonstrates exactly your problem and how it happens.  Quite possibly you are doing something wrong, or maybe `boost::variant` is fundamentally unusable with `unique_ptr`s.

Answer (score 1):

> Why would the compiler feel the need to synthesize a copy constructor and then complain that `std::unique_ptr` has private members?

It shouldn't, unless your standard library is non-compliant, and declares a private rather than deleted copy-constructor for `unique_ptr`; even then, it should only be synthesised if you haven't declared a move constructor.

If your class has `unique_ptr` members, or if you declare a move constructor, then it should complain that the copy constructor is deleted; and then only if you write code that attempts to copy it.

> Should the compiler not be aware that hidden copy and assignment with no body or simply not defined are to prevent trying to copy a `std::unique_ptr`?

That's right; except that the synthesised copy constructor and assignment are deleted, rather than not defined.

> And, why does declaring and defining copy constructors and assignment operators with an empty body make the compiler happy?

Because you are explicitly saying that you want it to use that (empty) code for copying, rather than whatever code it might (or might not) generate implicitly. It's a bad idea though; if your class is not copyable, then you want an attempt to copy it to generate an error, rather than incorrect runtime behaviour.

Comment: Does the presence of a move constructor not inhibit the generation of the copy constructor automatically?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Almost; it will be declared but deleted. I'll update my answer...

Comment: @MikeSeymour Yes ... `= delete` and the syntax is, if I recall, `MyCopyConstructor(const MyCopyCOnstructor &other) = delete`.  Is that right?

Comment: @Mushy: If you want to delete it yourself, then that is the syntax. But there's no need to, since it should be automatically deleted if you don't declare it yourself.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Problem is, if I don't declare a deleted copy constructor, the compiler attempts to synthesize one itself that is not deleted and then barfs all over my code.

Comment: @Mushy: Then either your compiler is broken, or you haven't declared a move constructor. I've no idea which is the case, since you haven't posted any code to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I am not sure what is going but I have declared copy to be = delete.